# CIL stack exchange instruction

Tags: cil

Is there a CIL instruction to exchange the first two elements in the stack?

Comment: Could you utilize the XOR Swap? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: nice hint! Problem is that CIL instructions pop their arguments from the stack. Since for the complete swap there are 3 xor ops required one would have to first duplicate the original stack values somehow. This is hard without using temporaries. Likely, a local variable would be more feasible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no single instruction exchange. However, using [stloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc.aspx), [pop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.pop.aspx), and [ldloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc.aspx), you should be able to accomplish your exchange.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to swap elements is to pop the top two elements to locals, then push them in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a [list of CIL instructions](http://en.csharp-online.net/CIL_Instruction_Set) there doesn't appear to be a single instruction that exchanges the two elements at the top of the stack. You'll have to do it the old pop/push way.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can create an assembly that does what you want to learn the IL for, then view the assembly in Reflector.  You can select the language you wish the code to be in, and IL is one of the options.  I did this when trying to figure out how to code a dynamic method...

Comment: All this shows is the compiler uses stloc and ldloc. But if I'm coding CIL from hand I want to know what's possible, not the patterns hardcoded into the C# compiler.