# How do I swap top two locations on .NET IL stack

Tags: cil, il

I wonder if it is possible to swap the top two locations on the .net IL stack without using non-stack storage. It is the sort of thing that stack machines can often do, but there does not appear to be an obvious instruction for that in IL.

The reason is that I need to calculate something a bit like f (x) + f (y). The x and y are the top two locations on the stack, and f has an IL implementation. This is trivial to do with intermediate storage but that is probably both slower and less convenient than if there was a swap.

Many thanks.

Comment: There isn't one, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191946/cil-stack-exchange-instruction However, if you could give some more details about what you want to do, perhaps there's an alternative that doesn't need a swap at all.

Comment: Many thanks, and sorry for the duplicate question (next time I must remember to search for both IL and CIL). I will just use intermediate storage.

Comment: JIT is not stupid and will probably optimize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CIL stack exchange instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191946/cil-stack-exchange-instruction)